# Insert many rows in to one column with same string in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get this query to work

```
INSERT INTO [ImportedDateRange] ([DataSet],[DateRange]) 
'webshop', (select DISTINCT cast([OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) from webshop)
```

I basically want it to look something like this:

```
DataSet     DateRange
webshop     01/10/2013
webshop     02/10/2013
webshop     03/10/2013
webshop     03/10/2013
```

where `webshop` is entered each time but each date range is copied over in to a new row.

Also  to check with the DateRange records for DataSet webshop already exist

thanks for any help and advice

Comment: Make sure you put all your requirements in the question... not as comments to answers!! So that everyone can see :)

Comment: sorry, will do in future, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert unique DateRange records for DataSet webshop in [ImportedDateRange] table from webshop table write as:

```
INSERT INTO [ImportedDateRange] 
([DataSet],[DateRange]) 
select DISTINCT 'webshop', cast(T2.[OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) from webshop T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from [ImportedDateRange] T1 where T1.[DateRange] = T2.[OrderCreatedDate])
```

Comment: This query will only insert unique records in ImportedDateRange table from webshop table which are not already in ImportedDateRange table. This is what the user wants...

Comment: @AntoRajaPrakash: OP states this requirement on one of the comment not in the question!

Comment: 'INSERT INTO [ImportedDateRange] 
([DataSet],[DateRange]) 
select DISTINCT 'webshop', cast(T2.[OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) from webshop T2 left join 
[ImportedDateRange] T1 on t2.[OrderCreatedDate] = t1.[DateRange] where t1.[DateRange] is null ' check this too an alternate with improved performance

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO [ImportedDateRange] ([DataSet],[DateRange]) 
SELECT DISTINCT  'webshop', CAST([OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) 
FROM   webshop
```

Comment: another quick question, would you know how to get it to check with the DateRange records for DataSet webshop already exist?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: if I ran that query twice it would insert the same data twice, any way to prevent this?

Comment: INSERT INTO [ImportedDateRange] ([DataSet],[DateRange]) 
SELECT DISTINCT  'webshop', CAST([OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) 
FROM   webshop WHERE DateRange NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CAST([OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) FROM webshop)

Comment: @KevinHolditch: No, you need to put a where condition on the select statement against the same table to ignore the existing values

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO [ImportedDateRange] 
([DataSet],[DateRange]) 
select DISTINCT 'webshop', cast([OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) from webshop
```

Answer (score 1):

'webshop' should be within the SELECT, try running the select on it's own as the output will be the same as will be inserted into the *ImportedDateRange* table.

```
INSERT INTO [ImportedDateRange] 
([DataSet], [DateRange]) 
select DISTINCT 'webshop', cast([OrderCreatedDate] as DATE) from webshop;
```